# ng-model not updating select value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem updating `<select>` with ng-init.

HTML:

```
<form data-ng-init="showStudent()">
<select id="studbranch" data-ng-model="student.branch"
    data-ng-options="obj.name for obj in branches track by obj.id" required>
    <option value="">-- Select Branch --</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Outputs:

```
<option value="">-- Select Branch --</option>
<option value="1">Branch 1</option>
<option value="2">Branch 2</option>
<option value="3">Branch 3</option>
```

In JS file:

```
$scope.branches = [{"id":"1","name":"Branch 1"},{"id":"2","name":"Branch 2"},{"id":"3","name":"Branch 3"}];

$scope.showStudent = function() {
    $.getJSON('student.php', function(data) {
        $scope.student = data[0]; $scope.$apply();
        alert($scope.student.branch);
    });
}
```

On page load (init), it alerts 3. That means student.branch is set to 3. But the select is not updated. It stays at default value. What could be wrong? Are the select values set after init?

If I add `$('#studbranch').val($scope.student.branch);` after the `alert()` it works fine.

Comment: Can you post `$scope.branches`

Comment: [{"id":"1","name":"Branch 1"},{"id":"2","name":"Branch 2"},{"id":"3","name":"Branch 3"}]

Comment: Your `select` output doesnt match what you have for `ng-options`

Comment: But the `select` is working fine on load. It just doesn't get updated on init call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try do that in angular way not jQuery

```
    app.controller(function($scope, $http){
    ...
$scope.student = [];
     $scope.showStudent = function() {
        $http.get('student.php').then( function(data) {
          angular.copy(data[0], $scope.student); 
           alert($scope.student.branch);
        });
    };
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working. I mean scope is not updated.

Comment: I think you meant `$http.get('student.php').success(function(data) {` It works now. But the main problem is still there. Thanks for the non-jquery way.

Comment: yes that right so do you want select to show data from $scope.student.branch ?

Comment: (`.then` shows a blank alert. `.success` works). Yes. $scope.student.branch now alerts "3", but `<option value="3">` is not selected.

Comment: can you do console.log($scope.student) and copy data from debug console ?

Comment: Object { name="Student Name", gender="1", branch="3", more...}

Comment: ok so because your $scope.student object is completely different then $scope.branches  you can to small trick as here : http://jsbin.com/vofol/5/edit

Comment: oh, so instead of student.branch, I should be setting student.branch.id. Thanks for the help. The problem is solved now, using the example given.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-options` should be formatted like so:

```
data-ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in branches track by obj.id"
```

Assigning the `ng-model` of the select to the right `id` will now update the select.

Comment: Thanks. There is no error now, and the select works fine. But the value is not changed. alert() shows 3, but the 3rd option is not selected.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. This doesn't work. It shows value in select, but I am unable to change them.